# Double pointer of array of int

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, double, programming-languages

Declaring:

```
int** a[3];
```

Can I say that 6 pointers are being declared or not?

My reasoning is that for every cell of the array I can enter it by either `*a[1]` or `**a[1]`.

Is this a correct assumption of I can only say that I've declared 3 pointer to pointers to 3 integers?

Comment: Pointer-to-pointers are not arrays and have absolutely nothing to do with arrays. In some cases you can use pointer-to-pointers together with dynamic allocation to create a look-up table which emulates an array, but isn't one. This is often a bad idea, however.

Answer (score 4):

> Can I say that 6 pointers are being declared or not?

No, this line declares an array of three pointers. Even though each pointer could be pointing to a pointer to `int`, initially they are not pointing to anything.

> every cell of the array I can enter it by either `*a[1]` or `**a[1]`

Each element of the array is a pointer to pointer to `int` - there is nothing else that could be inferred from the declaration.

You could use this declaration to make a 3-D array of integers, with each dimension having a different size, or you could stuff the entire array with `NULL`s. Nothing in the declaration limits the number of pointers that could be held by your array of three pointers.

Answer (score 1):

No, you've declared an array of 3 `int**` pointers with automatic storage duration, that's all. Another 3 somethings have not been spontaneously created.

For each element to have meaning, each would have to point to a pointer to an `int`. The following code assigns something meaningful to the first element of the array:

```
int main()
{
    int** a[3];
    int foo;
    int* bar = &foo;
    a[0] = &bar;
}
```

Finally, note that `a` could *decay* to an `int***` type if passed to a function with an `int***` type as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

All you can say is you've declared an array of 3 things - you may set those things to point to other things which in turn point to other things, but those other things are not created as a result of this declaration.